# Jquery Data table displays no data

Tags: c#, datatables

My requirement was to fetch details of users from active directory and then save it in a list and display it using Jquery Data tabale. I have managed to retrieve data from Active Directory..I was able to put the data in the List..I now have to display it using Jquery Data table..when i run the View, it just Displays the name of the columns but does not shows any data...

please check the code below for reference.

```
using ActiveDirectory.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ActiveDirectory.Controllers 
{
    public class DisplayUserController : Controller
    {
        // GET: DisplayUser

    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpGet]

public ActionResult UsersData()
{
    List<UsersModel> lstADUsers = new List<UsersModel>();
    string DomainPath = "LDAP://SGZ";
    DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath);
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");//first name
    SearchResult result;
    SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
    if (resultCol != null)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
        {
            string UserNameEmailString = string.Empty;
            result = resultCol[counter];
            if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname") &&
            result.Properties.Contains("mail") &&
            result.Properties.Contains("displayname"))
            {
                UsersModel objSurveyUsers = new UsersModel();
            objSurveyUsers.Email = (String)result.Properties["mail"][0] +
"^" + (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                objSurveyUsers.UserName = (String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
                objSurveyUsers.DisplayName = (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                lstADUsers.Add(objSurveyUsers);
            }
        }
    }

    return Json(new { data = lstADUsers }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    }

}
```

**View:**

```
@model ActiveDirectory.Models.UsersModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "User Details";
}

<div>

<style>
table, th, td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    align-content: center;
}
</style>
<div style="border:solid;width:100%;overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="table" align="center" style="width:100%" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Display Name</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mappiing</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#table').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
    "url": "@Url.Action("UsersData", "DisplayUser")", // action method URL
    "type": "GET",
    "datatype": "json"
},
columns: [
        { "data": "Display Name" },
        { "data": "User name" },
        { "data": "Email" },
        { "data": "Mapping" },

        ],
// other settings
    });
});
</script>
```

**User Model**

```
public class UsersModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool isMapped { get; set; }
}
```

**ScreenShot for GetData()**

```
 **ScreenShot for UserData()**
```

[image]

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: You have missed Mapping

Comment: Nope.. No errors ..It just displays the columns name

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee could you please let me know what i have missed and where?

Comment: can you show your UserModel schema

Comment: I have added it

Comment: so in action are you adding Mapping values?

Comment: Is the action actually being called and returning users?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders..When i run the UsersData method..it displays Json Data..but when i run GetData, it just displays the column names..

Comment: Is the browser calling the UsersData action when the page loads?

Comment: Do you get valid JSON back from the server? Also, do you have the correct names (i.e. is the JSON coming back with keys like "DisplayName" or "Display Name")? Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Your columns definition should be like this `columns:[{ "data": "DisplayName", "title":"Display Name " } ,.....]`

Comment: @annoyingmouse.. i am not getting any error in the console..and yes it returns back valid Json and also the names are correct..i will add a screen shot for both

Comment: @kulbans1991, your screenshot didn't come through.

Answer (score 0):

Data property names in your response and initialization code mismatch.

Use the following code for `columns` initialization options.

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "DisplayName" },
    { "data": "UserName" },
    { "data": "Email" },
    { "data": "isMapped" }
]
```